# I cannot find the error in this logic here and its driving me nuts

Tags: java, logic

```
    int number = 0;
    int factorOfTwo = 0;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the number to convert (0-255): ");
        number = input.nextInt();
    }  while (number< 0 || number > 255);

       System.out.println("The number " + number + " converted to binary is : ");

    for (factorOfTwo = 1; factorOfTwo <= 128; factorOfTwo*=2) {
        if (number / factorOfTwo >= 1){
            System.out.print("1");
            number -= factorOfTwo;
        }
        else System.out.print ("0");
    }
```

I am trying to convert integers to binary but I think the logic is off. For example 128 should display in binary as 1000 0000 but I get 11111110. Where am I messing up?

Comment: Try writing it out on paper. Why do you think `number / factorOfTwo >= 1` is correct? What happens if the number is `2` and you run this with `factorOfTwo == 1` to get the least significant bit? Also - think about the order you're outputting the bytes in - should you start with the highest value bit or the lowest value bit?

Comment: Got it! thank you good sir! edit: no i did not lol

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna kick yourself for being so close to the solution.

Here's the issue:  You're printing the binary digits from left-to-right, which indicates that they're in most significant bit order (MSB being "128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1").

However, your *loop* is generating the list *backwards*.  You *start* from 1, and go up to 128.

You actually want to start from 128 and go backwards to 1, dividing by 2 each step.

```
for (factorOfTwo = 128; factorOfTwo >= 1; factorOfTwo /= 2)
```

Comment: I have been starring at this thing for no joke, an entire hour. I kept thinking my error was in my while loop like the poster above wrote but I couldn't visualize it. Thank you!